# Is there a way to regenerate my world without destroying affected blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm wondering if there is a way to regenerate my world but only affect blocks that are part of the seed.  I.e. would update all the blocks in my snow biome to actually have snow on them, but not destroy my base that is in said location. Or spawn the multiple strongholds or spawn people in my already found town.

I don't have high hopes but thought i'd ask.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In past updates, biome changes have been retroactive. I logged into my original singleplayer world recently to find it was now a snow biome.

You can use a map editor (such as [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-18/)) or a game mod (such as Bukkit [WorldEdit](http://wiki.bukkit.org/WorldEdit) plugin) to delete the chunks you haven't built anything in. When you explore them again, they'll regenerate using the most up-to-date method.

If you really want all the latest terrain everywhere, use MCEdit to copy your base and export it as a schematic. Write down the world seed. Start a new world in Minecraft using the same seed, then exit Minecraft and use MCEdit to import your old base into the new world.

Comment: This is exactly what I did for 1.8. Also if you put everything you have on you in to chests, the chests will have the same stuff in your new world too.

Answer (score 0):

WorldEdit have an option to restore a defined cuboid from original world seed

Comment: This would destroy anything created in that cuboid.